# Number of spaces in Tab - OpenEdge

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

In OpenEdge the tab can be configured to any number of spaces, usually is configured to 4 spaces. 
To insert a tab in a text can be used: `~t`.
What I want to find is how many spaces have the tab set.

For example, I am reading a file line by line, and for each line I want to see how many spaces are at the beginning.

I am using:

```
iNoOfBeginningSpaces = index (cLine, left-trim (cLine)) - 1.
```

But if the line begins with 3 tabs then it gives me 3, and not the number of the spaces: `3 * spaces from tab`.
Is there a way to find the number of beginning spaces of a line, treating the tab as `x` numbers of spaces?

Comment: I don't know your requirements but I find scripting languages like Ruby, Python, or Perl better for these sorts of tasks - any reason you have to use OpenEdge?

Comment: Abe, I especially like all the UPPERCASE CHARACTERS in ABL, it makes the language super sexy!

Answer (score 1):

No.  Spaces and tabs are not the same thing.  You are getting confused by the fact that programming editors, word processors and printers convert tabs to spaces to get to tab stops.  But in a data file no such conversion occurs (unless you are saving the file from an editor that does such conversions).

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you how to check in your AppBuilder.

On the AppBuilder Menu you go to OPTIONS and then EDITING OPTIONS and there you can set how much "spaces" the editor uses for Tabs and Syntax indents. But this is basically for DISPLAY purposes within APPBUILDER.

Tom has given you the correct technical answer, a tab is a type of control character that can be interpreted differently by different apps. It has a different value than spaces.Below you can see the value of space and Horizontal Tab.

Char  Oct  Dec  Hex  Control-Key  Control Action

HT    11    9   9     ^I           Horizontal tab, move to next tab stop

=============================================

Char    Octal   Dec Hex Description

SP  40  32  20  Space

Comment: The tabs in the appbuilder only applies to internal editing of (for instance) .p files. Not how output of actual tabs are handled. They are, exactly as stated by @TomBascom - tabs.

Comment: @Jensd Is what I said :-) oh maybe the way i said it was a bit confusing - updated